# Does this PDE has solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Consider the cauchy problem, $5u_x+2u_y=7$ with $u=1$ in line $2x-5y=0$.

Does it has no solution, unique solution or infinitely many solution?

Characteristic is parallel to the initial line. So I try to take different initial line and solve it but it seems something is not compatible and I couldn't find any solution. please give me a hint

Comment: If I take x axis as my initial curve , with initial conditions $u(x,0)=h(x),h(0)=1$ ; will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$5u_x+2u_y=7$$
The general solution (from method of characteristics or other method) is :
$$u(x,y)=\frac72 y+F(2x-5y)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).

You can check it directly in putting $u=\frac72 y+F(2x-5y)$ into $5u_x+2u_y=7$.

CONDITION : $u=1$ on $2x-5y=0$
$$1=\frac72 y+F(0)$$
This is impossible because $\frac72 y+F(0)$ which is not constant cannot be equal to a constant $=1$ , what ever the function $F$ is.

Thus there is no solution which satisfies both the PDE and the specified condition.

WITH a DIFFERENT CONDITION : $u(x,0)=h(x)$

$$h(x)=0+F(2x-0)$$
With $X=2x\quad \implies\quad h(X/2)=F(X).\quad$The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=2x-5y$.
$$u(x,y)=\frac72 y+h(\frac{2x-5y}{2})$$
This is valid what ever $h(0)$ is.

Moreover, if $h(0)=1$ then $u(0,0)=h(0)=1.\quad$ And $u(x,y)$ is not constant on the line $2x-5y=0$  but is : $u=\frac72 y+1=\frac75 x+1$.